# How React Component expose data to external app?

Tags: reactjs

Let's say i have a React Component `<forecast id="test"/>`. And i want import this component into a legacy project which only have `jquery` involved.

Is it possible to get the value of this component like `document.querySelector('#test').value`?

I got some information from React website, that we cannot access data from outside the component. The recommended way is dispatching data from inside of the component.

My question is, the way to `dispatching` data is behind of the component implementation. Is it means that i have to read the source code of component in case i don't know how it works?

If this is true, i won't think React is free to inject to any product, it cost too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a plain JS wrapper to do it. Something like this might work

```
function Forecast(element) {
   this.value = initialValue;
   React.render(<forecast onChange={onChange.bind(this)}/>, element);

   function onChange(newValue) {
     this.value = newValue;
   }

}
```

Comment: Which means the component has to provide an API like `onChange` in your example, to have the internal data accessible, right?

Comment: Right. It's sort of a convential name for a callback, but you can pick some other name or have multiple callbacks, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to inject some React to your project you should do it with some independent part of your system.
If you have tightly coupled code base its always high cost to add any new technology to it. So its not a React problem. Try to find some independent module or subapplication in your system and move it to React. If you cannot find one, try to refactor existing code first.

Comment: What if the React Component dispatching data in inconsistent way? I mean different component written by different developer. They may dispatch data in their preferred way.  Like Component `<A />` dispatch her data by using `flux`, Component `<B />` dispatch her data by triggering event in `jquery` way.
Do i have to implement those mechanisms in my application? Even it's a brand new project, still seems not so good! 
Am i thinking in wrong way?

Comment: If Component implemented right it doesn't dispatch anything. It may receive some function to deal with data outside of it. For example you have  a component for users feed: <Feed />. And this component need to load more items in some case. Than component developed in right React-style would except some function for this. <Feed loadMore={yourLoadMoreFunction} />. So component doesn't know about how to load more items to feed. Implementation of yourLoadMoreFunction is up to you.